# How to replace keyclock JpaUserProviderprovider with your own

Tags: java, microservices, keycloak, licensing

How to replace keyclock JpaUserProvider  with your own?

Hi. It is required to call an external microservice to check the license when adding a user and roles to the keyclock. I need to use my custom provider insteed JpaUserProvider. How to replace it? In what config or smthing else i need to do this?